Girl high dives with horse and goes blind
There was an american movie that came out in early to mid 90's about a girl who would ride a horse while it jumped off a high dive into water.  This was a show that people would pay to watch, maybe like a circus performance sort of thing.  
During a dive she didn't close her eyes and she goes blind.  She eventually learns how to get around while blind.  She may start jumping again but I'm not sure.
She was a brunette, mid to late teens.  I don't remember what the horse/s looked like.

Curious, was this question asked because this one reminded you of it? Because it reminded me of it, which was why it was so fresh in my brain... not that I had any difficulty recalling the title.

@Catija i was trying to remember it earlier today or yesterday, but couldn't remember the name.  that other question jogged my memory that i intended to ask the question here.  :-D

The film is called Wild Hearts Can't Be Broken. 

Wild Hearts Can’t Be Broken is a 1991 film about Sonora Webster Carver, a rider of diving horses and is based on events in her life as told in her memoir A Girl and Five Brave Horses.

